# How does this instance declaration result in an ambiguous case?

Tags: haskell

The following snippet

```
data Tree k v = ETree | Node {  leftTreeOf  :: Tree k v,
                                rightTreeOf :: Tree k v,
                                tKey        :: k,
                                tVal        :: v
                                }

instance Show s => Show (Tree s s) where
    show = showTree 0
```

yields

```
Illegal instance declaration for `Show (Tree s s)'
  (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
   where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
   and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
   Use -XFlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
In the instance declaration for `Show (Tree s s)'
```

I looked it up, and the restriction that `-XFlexibleInstances` lifts is in place to prevent ambiguous instances from being declared.
How does having two type variables allow an ambiguous case though?

```
instance Show s => Show (Tree s) where
    show = showTree 0
```

worked fine when I only needed one type variable.

Comment: `FlexibleInstances` has nothing to do with ambiguous instances. You cannot write an ambiguous instance with `FlexibleInstances` alone. Typeclass instances must have a very specific form (namely, the form that the error tells you they must have) which is specified by the [Haskell 98](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#undecidable-instances) report. FlexibleInstances removes this requirement and consequently makes your code non-conformant to the Haskell 98 standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't think it through.

If anyone else is having this problem, it requires 2 different type variable to be supplied to allow 2 different Show-able types:

```
instance (Show sk, Show sv) => Show (Tree sk sv) where
    show = showTree 0
```

Then any contained functions (in this case showTree), need a similar signature.